# liferay domain url redirected automatically to old domain

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I've changed my url domain in Lifera (from domain1.com to domain2.com)y. In control panel->Portal->Configuration I've changed to domain2.com, but when I go to login or control panel, automatically the browser change to domain1.com

Is there any other place to change?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the file, server.xml of tomcat, that I have to replace.